# FileLoadException: During runtime for an assembly "package referenced" (local nuget) from asp.net core csproj

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Here's the situation what I am facing with:

Asp.net core .cs web host project has a reference to package "ABC", version 1.0.1. If I set the package source to restore ABC directly from the feed and build, run the application it all works fine. Let's say, If I have the code base of ABC (.net standard assembly) and I want to make some changes and test/debug it locally, this is what I usually does:

I make changes in ABC project, create a local nuget package (.nupkg and .snupkg) with a version greater than or equal to 1.0.1
Set the package source in asp.net core project to restore from the local folder where I have the nuget pkg (or MS VS Offline Pkgs folder) and build, run the project.
Though it restores,builds fine, I am getting a runtime error from the host:

*FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ABC, Version=1.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

If I follow the same steps and tried to restore/debug local nuget pkg for a .net core console app, it works perfectly fine. This behaviour is happening only in asp.net core web app.

Appreciate your valuable inputs. Thank you.

Comment: You aren't changing the version number, so the runtime is looking for the old package, not finding it, and failing appropriately. You need to update the version number when you update the package.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Actually, asp.net core web app does packagereference to ABC (.net standard library).  I tried generating ABC nuget package in higher versions but still web app fails during runtime (though restored/builds successfully). As I said, local nuget pkgs for debugging works perfectly fine for .net core console app - this issue happens only in asp.net core webapp.